# Saving a For Each HTML Table in Flask

Tags: html, json, flask

I have created a HTML table with a for each loop to generate all the data in the table, the issue I am having is when I try and save the data after a cell is updated on the page.
I am currently using json.dump to try and save the data but it only does the first record and stops. Help would be appreciated.

Flask Code

```
def Control():
    with open('./Master.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
        data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        first_line = True
        Risks = []
        savepatch= {}
        for row in data:
            if not first_line:
                Risks.append({
                    "Catagory": row[0],
                    "Ref": row[1],
                    "WorkAct": row[2],
                    "SubAct": row[3],
                    "Hazard": row[4],
                    "Result": row[5],
                    "ERC1": row[6],
                    "ERC2": row[7],
                    "ERC3": row[8],
                    "ERC4": row[9],
                    "ERC5": row[10]})                
            else:
                first_line = False
    if request.method != "POST":
        return render_template(
            'Control.html',
            title='Floof',
            year=datetime.now().year,
            message='Core Controls.',
            Risks = Risks)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        updater = request.form.items()
        for key, val in updater:
            savepatch.update(updater)
        with open("Risk.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(savepatch, f)
```

HTML Code

```
{% for Risks in Risks %}
        <TR>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Reference" name="Reference" value={{ Risks.Ref }} readonly /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Activity" name="Activity" value="{{Risks.Act}}" readonly /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="SubActivity" name="SubActivity" value={{Risks.SubAct}} readonly /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Hazard" name="Hazard" value="{{Risks.Hazard}}" readonly /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Results" name="Result" value="{{Risks.Result}}" readonly /> </TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Results" name="ERC1" value="{{Risks.ERC1}}"/></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Results" name="ERC2" value="{{Risks.ERC2}}" /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Results" name="ERC3" value="{{Risks.ERC3}}" /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Results" name="ERC4" value="{{Risks.ERC4}}" /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" id="Results" name="ERC5" value="{{Risks.ERC5}}" /></TD>
            </TR>
        {% endfor %}
    </TABLE>
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around with the code I have it almost perfect, the outstanding issue is every line below the first starts with a , and for the last entry of each row I have had to add in a ; but apart from that it is perfect the code is as follows

HTML code:

```
{% for risk in Risks %}
    <TR>
        {% for r in risk %}
        <TD>
            <input type="text" id="Reference" name="Reference" value="{{ risk[r] }}">
            {% endfor %}
    </TR>
    {% endfor %}
```

I had to put the value item in quotation marks so it displayed everything in the field but apart from that it is exactly as above. The changes come from the flask side of things

```
elif request.method == "POST":
    savepatch = request.form.getlist('Reference')
    midform = [l.split(':') for l in ':'.join(savepatch).split(r';')]
    with open("Risk.csv",mode='w', newline='\n') as csv_file:
        data = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        data.writerow(["Category", "Ref", "WorkAct", "SubAct", "Hazard", "Outcome", "RiskCont1", "RiskCont2", "RiskCont3", "RiskCont4", "RiskCont5", "RiskCont6", "RiskCont7", "RiskCont8", "RiskCont9", "RiskCont10"])
        for item in midform:
            data.writerow(item)
```

It is a work around and it puts the catagories as the first line in the file then everything falls into line after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  {% for risk in Risks %}
            <TR>
               {% for r in risk %}
                <TD><input type="text" id="Reference" name="Reference" value={{ risk[r] }}
               {% endfor %}
            </TR>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, it hasn't quite fixed the issue but I will look into it further as it is a slightly more elegant code, still having the issue with the saving now it is just  {} but doing earlier research it appears that I might need an init for it to work properly